# How to get Bluetooth device MAC address using Swift mbientlab bluetooth scanner

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, bluetooth, mac-address

Working with the MbientLab metawear MetaMotionRL motion sensor. Building mobile app in flutter with both an Android and iOS frontend. Access to the device is via mbientlab API. Using Java for Android and Swift for iOS.

On the Java side I detect devices via flutter_blue. This includes the mac address for devices. When a user selects a device from a list, the app uses the mac address to connect via the mbient API.

But... I don't know how to do the same on the Swift side.

And... mbient API has its own device scanning feature. Which is nice since it only finds mbient devices; not other bluetooth devices. So, I'm using that. But, I can't seem to find the mac address in the API -- not for a device that is not yet connected. I want to display the mac address of all nearby devices before connecting so that if there are multiple the user can choose based on the mac address ... which is printed on the device.

So, I'm looking for the answer to either of these questions ... using Swift:

1. How does one connect to a device via the mbient API with a given mac address?
2. How does one get the mac address from the mbient device scanner?

Here's the Swift code for using the mbient scanner:

```
            MetaWearScanner.shared.startScan(allowDuplicates: false) { (device: MetaWear) in
                let id: String = device.peripheral.identifier.uuidString
                logger.trace("Found metawear device name:'\(device.name)' id:\(id)")
                self.foundDevicesById[id] = device
            }
```

There are many properties of a device -- including sub-objects. But I cannot find mac address. Well, this is a mac address property, but it is not loaded until the device is connected. Am I missing something? Is the mac address in there?

I didn't write the Java code. I don't understand it. It's complicated, but it works. It's embedded in the MainActivity.java file. Here are the parts that seem relevant:

```
private BtleService.LocalBinder serviceBinder;

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    ///< Typecast the binder to the service's LocalBinder class
    serviceBinder = (BtleService.LocalBinder) service;
}

private void retrieveBoard(String macAddress) {
    BluetoothManagBluetoothManagerer btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = btManager.getAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
    _board = serviceBinder.getMetaWearBoard(remoteDevice);
}
```

If I could do similar in Swift, that would be great. I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot access the MAC address of a BLE device directly in iOS. This is by design. The only identifier available is `CBPeripheral.identifier`. This is a fairly stable identifier, but it can change from time to time. Each phone will assign a different identifier to each BLE device. This prevents using BLE MAC addresses to track users.

That said, for your described problem you shouldn't need an identifier. You can just put the CBPeripheral objects in a list, and when the user selects one, you can connect to it.

If you control the firmware of the device, you can make the MAC address available through a characteristic or advertising. But in the general case, there is no way to access this information.

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful to know that it cannot be done. ... but I do need an identifier for display. The user will be confused if they get a list of choices that all look the same. Do you want: A, A or A (see what I mean?). The ID may not allow the user to know which device is which without connecting, but it will allow them to go through the list via process of elimination (A-x is the wrong one so I'll try A-y). I hope you get what I mean. ... and I do not control the device firmware.

Comment: Is it common for the user to have multiple of these devices nearby? The normal thing to use is the name (`.name`), though it's possible these are always the same. (If you can set the name, you can include a short random identifier, which is useful.) Another useful tool is the RSSI. It can give you a very rough sense of how far away the device is. When discovering devices, it is common to exclude devices whose RSSI is very low because they are likely a long way away. It is also something you can display in real-time to help the user identify the correct device if they are technically savvy.

Comment: You can also explore what else the device advertises. Some devices provide some useful information in their Manufacturer Data section. Your options really depend on your precise device.

Comment: Thanks. Great info. It's a requirement to account for multiple devices. I only have one device which reports name as the product name. I assume they all do the same ... so not useful. ... I have no requirement to exclude devices with low RSSI (far away) and they could have multiple close by. but ... maybe I should order by RSSI -- which is basically distance; closest first. It would be very unusual if the devices were on top of each other and user will typically be holding the one they want. Hmm. ... Thanks for tip about manufacturer data; that might be useful. ... Sending good karma.

Comment: This is odd: reading the mac address for a device found by the scanner works now. When I tried it a few days ago, mac was blank. The API docs say it will be blank until connect and you (and other folks online) say it won't work. But... it does now. How strange.

Comment: In what way is "mac" blank? What property do you mean?

Comment: MetaWear.mac. MetaWear class encapsulates a device. I guess that should be in the question.

Comment: If they've built a custom protocol to expose the MAC, then it would make perfect sense that the SDK would automatically fetch it after connection. I've built exactly that kind of protocol before. It has nothing to do with CoreBluetooth (or even Bluetooth really). You'll have to explore the vendor's documentation. (Depending on how they implemented this, it also makes perfect sense that it would be cached. All depends on the firmware and the SDK)